# Android. How to capture image from camera and store it in server?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am new to android. I want to capture image using camera and store it in server. Below code is to open camera and capture image.

```
 private void openCamera() {
    requestPermissions(TYPE_IMAGE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,contentURI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA);
}
```

After capturing image I want that image to store in server directly. Thanks in advance. Need Help.
**Manifest file is below:**
[image]

Comment: Follow [This](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics) . And for sending image to server you need to make a Network call . I see you added `RetroFit` tag with question . Use `Multipart` request to send image to server . DONE ...

Comment: I am using Multipart request "RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
                    MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("aadhar", file.getName(), requestFile);"

Comment: for sending the image without multipart you can change it to a string (base64) and send it normally.

https://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2016/10/android-convert-image-base64-string-base64-string-image.html

Comment: See the link given by @ADM

Comment: I want my image to save it in server

Comment: after capture you saving it with a name that you decided so take a path of that image with the name that you put it  and upload it after 3 sec

Comment: can you give me some example? @Eazyz

Comment: hope this will help you @Muthu http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/

Comment: that helped me a lot. But  I want that do be done with retrofit @user7596908

Answer (score 2):

To store the image captured from camera, override the the `activityResult` callback this way:

```java
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && requestCode==CAMERA_CODE)
        {
                try {

                    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                    Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

                    //if you want to encode the image into base64
                    if (imageBitmap!=null) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
           String encodeImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);

            //You can send your image to server
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

           }
       }
```

**EDIT**: If you want the image to be saved as file into storage then manipulate it from there, you will have to proceed differently.

- First, you will have to create a file path inside **xml** subfolder of **res** folder and the file path here called `file_paths.xml` can be like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="my_images"
        path="Android/data/YOUR_PACKAGE/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

- Next you will have to create a provider inside Manifest and add the file_path resource as the FILE_PROVIDER_PATH:

```xml
<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
```

- Then inside your code(java), you will have to generate a unique path/name for the image (you can just use the following method to do so):

```java
  private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        String timeStamp =
                new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                        Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "IMG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir =
                getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        imageFilePath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
```

The variable `imageFilePath` here is a member of the current class because we need it to be accessible anywhere in that class.

You can then start the camera intent but this time you will provide the output(where data will be stored):

```java
Intent picture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (picture.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {

            File photo = null;
                      try {


                          photo = createImageFile();

                     } catch (IOException ex) {

                  }

                 if (photo != null) {
                    Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                           "YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME.provider",
                        photo);

              picture.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(picture, CAMERA_CODE);

            }
```

- And the last more thing will be to listen to activity result and act accordingly:

```java
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
        {

                try {
                    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                    //our imageFilePath that contains the absolute path to the created file 
                    File file = new File(imageFilePath);
                    Bitmap imageBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media
                            .getBitmap(getContentResolver(), Uri.fromFile(file));
                  //do whatever else after
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
           }
    }
```

Comment: I am not able to store the same image(which I captured) in server. Instead of captured image, some other image is stored in server

Comment: check the edited answer. what's that image ? black background images or just images from your phone? It may result on the path you are providing too I guess

Comment: what's the photoFile in that if condition?                                                         if (photo != null) {
                    Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                           "YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME.provider",
                        photoFile);

Comment: it's photo and not photoFile. Sorry

Comment: Getting this Error." java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference  "

Comment: are you sure you proceeded step by step creating the resource, variables following the order? because the error there is about XML resource

Comment: Yes. I did the same as you posted here

Comment: okay, can I see the structure of your res folder and xml subfolder? then can you post the manifest?

Comment: I just saw the manifest is okay and the structure too. Can I see how you implemented that in code? does it at least opening the camera? and coming back to calling activity?

Comment: No its not opening the camera. If I click the button to open camera the app crashes.

Comment: what's the code inside your button onClickListener?

Comment: Inside onClickListener I am calling the dialog box to choose the image from gallery or take photo using camera

Comment: can you post the complete process? What's the code when someone chooses to open camera? does the dialog box appear?

Comment: can you  give me your mail id so that i can send my complete code

Comment: asimbahwegracier@gmail.com that's my email address, you can send me the code

Comment: Got my file? I send

Comment: Yes. I will come back to you asap